# c++: Difference between member and non member functions

Tags: c++, oop

What is the difference between member and non-member functions in C++?

Comment: Interesting, I had thought the answers would be rather dry, but it seems that we all have very varied opinions about this!

Answer (score 41):

There are several differences between a member function (which I will now call *method*) and a free function (which I will now call *function*).

First, let's just state that they are not *so* different. Object code can generally be compiled down to C (or assembly) which are procedural languages with no notion of methods. Both methods and functions are then *called* like subroutines.

Now that this is out of the way, let's look at the differences. They can be classified in two categories: conceptual and syntactic.

**Syntactically**

The syntax is the obvious part of any language, so it's the easiest to get out of the way.

First note: there are two different kinds of methods in C++ (and a number of other languages), the `static` methods and regular methods.

Both kinds of methods have full access to the class internals (`protected` and `private` sections) as well (of course) as access to the class `public` interface.

`static` methods are equivalent to `friend` functions (apart from some scoping differences).

Within a regular method, a special keyword (`this` in C++) allows access to the current object on which the method has been invoked (via the `.`, `->`, `.*` or `->*` operators).

A regular method may be `const` and/or `volatile` qualified, enabling it for (respectively) `const` and/or `volatile` qualified objects. For example, a non-`const` method cannot be called on a `const` object. This can be seen as qualifying `this` within the method, ie `void Foo::bar() const` has a `this` of type `Foo const*`.

A regular method may be marked as `virtual`. Virtuality enables runtime polymorphism by enabling overriding. I won't extend on this mechanism here, let's just note that functions cannot be virtual.

One often ignored point, is that methods (both `static` and regular) are scoped within the class. This is important for name lookup (of other methods or attributes/variables) as it means that the elements of the class have priority during lookup from a method on the elements declared outside of the class.

Since the qualification using `this->` before attribute or methods is not mandatory, this comes handy in regular methods, though it may introduce subtle bugs. In static methods, it avoids qualifying by the class name the static attributes and methods one whishes to access.

Now that the main syntactic differences have been asserted, let's check the conceptual differences.

**Conceptually**

OOP is generally about tying together state and behavior (of this state). This is done by creating classes which group attributes (state) and behavior (methods) and (in theory) stating that only the methods can act on the state. Therefore, in OOP, the methods are responsible for implementing the behavior of the class.

The methods participate to the encapsulation of state (freeing clients from the implementation detail) and to the preservation of the class invariants (statements about the class state that hold true from its birth to its death, whatever you do with it).

**C++**

In C++, as we have seen previously, this is done by using different access levels (`public`, `protected` and `private`) and granting access to the non-`public` levels to a restricted portion of the code. Generally attributes will be private and thus only accessible to the class methods (and maybe some friends, for syntax quirks).

*Note: I urge you not to use `protected` attributes, it's hard to track down their modifications and since the set of derived classes is unbounded... their implementation cannot be changed easily afterward.*

However, beware that C++ discourages from bloating the interface with lots of methods.

The trouble is that because methods are responsible of maintaining invariants, the more there are and the more the responsability is spread, making it more difficult to track down bugs and ensure correctness. Also, since methods depends on the class internals, it makes change more costly.

Instead, in C++, it is generally advised to write a minimal set of methods and delegating the rest of the behavior to non-`friend` functions (as long as it doesn't increase the cost too much).

- See Sutter's take on `std::string` in [Monolith Unstrung](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm).
- The delegation to non-friend methods was emphasized by Sutter in its [Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm) in which he states that functions that are delivered with the class (in the same file/same namespace) and use the class, are logically part of the class interface. He restates in Exceptional C++.

This answer is becoming rather long-winded, yet I suspect that I have overlooked differences that other would find critical... oh well.

Answer (score 22):

A (non-static) *member function* has an implicit `this` argument, a non-member doesn't.

Syntactically, you pass that implicit argument on the left of the `.` or `->` operator `like.so()` or `like->so()`, instead of as a function argument `so( like )`.

Likewise, when declaring a member function, you need to do so in the class of which it is a member:

```
class Class {
public:
    void a_public_member_function();
};
```

Non-member functions are instead declared outside any class (C++ calls this "at namespace scope").

(Non-static) member functions can also be *virtual*, but non-member functions (and static member functions) cannot.

Comment: +1 for clear answer, and for not confusing "non-static" with "static" member functions.

Answer (score 10):

A non-`static` member function is invoked on objects of the class it belongs to. It has implicitly access to the `this` pointer representing the current object. Through this pointer, it may access other members easily and with full access privileges (i.e. access `private` members).

A non-member function has no implicit `this`. In the sample below, `bar` is a member function while `freebar` is not. Both do more or less the same, but note how `bar` gets an implicit object pointer via `this` (also only `bar` has privileged access to `foo`'s members, `freebar` only has access to public members).

```
class foo {
public:

    void bar() {
        this->x = 0; // equivalent to x = 0;
    }

    int x;
};

void freebar(foo* thefoo) {
   thefoo->x = 1;
}


// ... 
foo f;
f.bar();
// f.x is now 0

freebar(&f);
// f.x is now 1
```

Semantically a member function is more than just *a function with an implicit this parameter*. It is meant to define the *behaviour* of an object (i.e. a car object would have `drive()`, `stop()` as member functions).

Note that there are also `static` member functions which have full privileges but don't get an implicit `this` nor are they invoked through an instance of the class (but rather through the full name of the class).

Comment: `this` is an implementation hangover of the language. Personally I would stress the relationship of the method acting on a particular object rather than focusing on how that relationship is implemented. In 99.9% of cases you don't actually use this yet you still interact with members of the object (the only place I use it is in operator= to return a reference to self).

Comment: I edited my text a bit, putting emphasis on the semantic meaning of a member function. H

Comment: @Martin It is an implementation hangover, but it is critical for understanding the differences and their consequences in C++.

Comment: I think this needs a more finer distinction. A member function only has access to `this` if it is non-static.

Comment: Added a note on `static` member functions.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler: I disagree. In-fact I think it hinders newcomers in there understanding of OO; because they then apply this knowledge of an implementation detail to other parts of the language. The concept should be explained in terms of OO not how C++ implements the concept. As explained above you practically never need to use the this pointer. If you remove `this` from your examples the code still works exactly the same.

Answer (score 7):

In the following code, `f()` is a member function of class `Sample`, and `g()` is a non-member function:

```
class Sample
{
  void f();
};

void g();
```

Its very simple. Since `f()` is a member of the class `Sample`, so its called member function (of class `Sample`). And since `g()` is not member of any class, so its called non-member function.

Answer (score 3):

A member function is invoked on an object and has access to the fields of the class.

Member functions can be polymorphic (via the `virtual` keyword) which is essential for OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions get called on instances and have a `this` pointer available; non-members don't.

Comment: does this mean, that all functions of a class are member functions except static functions?

Comment: @Luke: Yes. (I write this thinking dam somebody is going to point out something obscure I have forgotten). PS. I am not your father (May the 4 by yesterday)

Comment: @Luke, no, it doesn't. Those answers that confuse static with non-static member functions are wrong. See @mmutz answer for a correct description.