# QT, C++, cannot call member function without object

Tags: c++, qt, oop

In my mainwindow.cpp is where call is made. Call is supposed to occur on button clicked event. Error says `cannot call member function 'void Foo::setFooAttributes(A&, B&, C&, D&)' without object`.

```
void MainWindow::on_generateButton_clicked()
{

  setCreator(ui->interfaceCreatorName->text());
  setAlternateName(ui->interfaceAlternateName->text());
  setDomain(ui->interfaceDomain->text().toInt());
  QString filename = getCreator() + "'s " + getAlternateName() + ".txt";
  QFile file( filename );
  A a; B b; C c; D d;
  Foo::setFooAttributes(a,b,c,d); //ERROR: cannot call member function without object
  generateTop(file);
  generateMiddle(file);
  generateSecondaryMid(file);
  generateLast(file);
  generateTertiaryMid(file, a, b, c, d);

}
```

The function itself looks like this:

```
void Foo::setFooAttributes(A &aFoo, B &bFoo, C &cFoo, D &dFoo){

   aFoo.stopPoint = MainWindow.ui->aInterfaceStopPoint->text().toDouble();
   aFoo.rate = MainWindow.ui->aInterfaceRate->text().toInt();
   aFoo.domain = MainWindow.ui->aInterfaceDomain->text().toInt();
   aFoo.length = MainWindow.ui->aInterfaceLength->text().toInt();

   bFoo.stopPoint = MainWindow.ui->bInterfaceStopPoint->text().toDouble();
   bFoo.rate = MainWindow.ui->bInterfaceRate->text().toInt();
   bFoo.domain = MainWindow.ui->bInterfaceDomain->text().toInt();
   bFoo.length = MainWindow.ui->bInterfaceLength->text().toInt();

   cFoo.stopPoint = MainWindow.ui->cInterfaceStopPoint->text().toDouble();
   cFoo.rate = MainWindow.ui->cInterfaceRate->text().toInt();
   cFoo.domain = MainWindow.ui->cInterfaceDomain->text().toInt();
   cFoo.length = MainWindow.ui->cInterfaceLength->text().toInt();

   dFoo.stopPoint = MainWindow.ui->dInterfaceStopPoint->text().toDouble();
   dFoo.rate = MainWindow.ui->dInterfaceRate->text().toInt();
   dFoo.domain = MainWindow.ui->dInterfaceDomain->text().toInt();
   dFoo.length = MainWindow.ui->dInterfaceLength->text().toInt();

}
```

I put the rest of code including foo.h in paste here [pastebin source](http://pastebin.com/CsW5Hf2c)

I first tried calling `setFooAttributes(a,b,c,d);` without `Foo::` but that gave me error like `'setFooAttributes' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: The question is about basic C++. The way you call Foo::setFooAttributes is only applicable to static functions. Otherwise you need to do exactly what error says - have an object of class Foo. Foo f; f.setFooAttributes();

Comment: Hi, ty for quick reply. I would like to set attributes for multiple objects at once instead of a.setAttributes, b.setAttributes, etc. Ideally the call would be "setFooAttributes(a,b,c,d);" but compiler griped about scope. I didnt know how else to fix scope issue so i made it as shown above

Comment: You could make the function a non-class function. Just move it out of the class and call it without `Foo::`.

Comment: @Bugfinger ty for suggestion. I don't know what to do now. I had my heart set on having that function being part of the Foo class, but it only works if I have it outside of that class. Is there anyway I can make it work inside that class?

Comment: @Duhmfuhk: Well, you already got the answer of making it static. :) ... Whether to make it static or move it outside the class depends on the use case. Both might be alright. More info on non-member functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920916/c-difference-between-member-and-non-member-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your `Foo::setFooAttributes` a `static` member function, since it doesn't operate on a "this" instance.

While you're at it, if A/B/C/D are actually the same type (or a subtype of a common type), you might consider removing all the duplication, to better follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle:

```
template <typename A> static void Foo::setFooAttributes(Foo &aFoo, int iface) {

   aFoo.stopPoint = MainWindow.ui->interfaceStopPoint[iface]->text().toDouble();
   aFoo.rate = MainWindow.ui->interfaceRate[iface]->text().toInt();
   aFoo.domain = MainWindow.ui->interfaceDomain[iface]->text().toInt();
   aFoo.length = MainWindow.ui->interfaceLength[iface]->text().toInt();

}

static void Foo::setFooAttributes(Foo &aFoo, Foo &bFoo, Foo &cFoo, Foo &dFoo) {

    setFooAttributes(aFoo, 0);
    setFooAttributes(bFoo, 1);
    setFooAttributes(cFoo, 2);
    setFooAttributes(dFoo, 3);
}
```

(This would need you to convert each of `{a,b,c,d}InterfaceStopPoint`, `{a,b,c,d}InterfaceRate`, `{a,b,c,d}InterfaceDomain` and `{a,b,c,d}InterfaceLength` into arrays, instead of four individual variables).

You could even improve on this by using a loop or a variable-arity template function, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for exceptional answer! While we're on the topic, you wouldn't happen to know why A, B, C, D object declarations in mainwindow.h are giving error: "class does does not name a type" ? it happened when i first changed function in question to static. Furthermore, compiler now gripes about error "expected primary-expression before '.' token ". It says so for every member initialization in setFooAttributes

Comment: Ah. `MainWindow` is a class, correct, not a member of `Foo`? So `MainWindow.ui` should probably be `MainWindow::ui` in each case. This is assuming of course that the `ui` member is static; if not, then you need to make it static, or use a reference to a `MainWindow` instance of trying to access an instance member via the class. Regarding "class does not name a type", perhaps it doesn't? Are there actually types named A, B, C and D? You don't show any declarations of them.