# How to access the object array in c++?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming. My goal is to realize the pancake sort in C++ without using STL. I have 3 classes, they are `pancake`, `pancakepile` and `MpancakePiles`. I have a question about the access to the object array. My code is as following:

- My pancake pile is a 3D pile and Z is it's height.
- So for a single pancake pile, it has Z pancakes.
- I need to find the max size's index of these Z pancakes.

However, I don't know how to access the object array, like what should I fill in the `???` area if I want to process the object array `size` inside the `pancake P`. `Max` is a defined function.
There is no particular reason for not using STL. `N` is a static size, `N=512`. `burnt=0` means burnt side face down.

```cpp
int Max(int size[], int n)
{
    int mi,i;
    for(mi=0,i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(size[i]> size[mi])
            mi=i;
    return mi;
}


class pancake
{
  public:
    int size;
    bool burnt;
    void flip_pancake()
    {
      burnt=~burnt;
    }
};


class pancakepile
{
  public:
    pancake P[N];
    int Z;  
    void pan_sort_ascending()
     {

       int mi=Max(???,Z);
         ......
     } 

}
```

Comment: Why no STL? What's `N` in `pancake P[N];`? If you flip a pancake, it gets burnt and then unburnt?

Comment: btw there is only one STL and for the pedantics: STL is the library that preceeded the c++ standard library, I have never seen it and I doubt you did ;)

Comment: There is no particular reason for not using STL. N is a static size N=512. Because burnt=0 means burnt side face down.

Comment: its unclear what you are asking. " I don't know to access the object array," you already do access elements of an array in `Max`, maybe you just need to do the same

Comment: when you have to explain things like "burnt means burnt face face down" then this is a good indicator that you should give better names to your variables. For example when the variables meaning is "burnt face down" then `burnt_face_down` is way better than `burnt`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will take care of that, thanks. @user463035818

Answer (score 2):

You throw away your current implementation of `pan_sort_ascending`, and replace it with a call to `std::sort`, passing a function that describes which of two pancakes should go below the other.

```
#include <algorithm>

// A pancake is smaller than another if it's size is less
bool pancake_less(const pancake & lhs, const pancake & rhs)
{
    return lhs.size < rhs.size;
}

// sorts smallest first
void pancakepile::pan_sort_ascending()
{
    std::sort(P, P + Z, pancake_less);
}
```

Now if you want a `pan_sort_descending`, you can just flip the logic of the comparison

```
// A pancake is larger than another if it's size is greater
bool pancake_greater(const pancake & lhs, const pancake & rhs)
{
    return lhs.size > rhs.size;
}

// sorts largest first
void pancakepile::pan_sort_descending()
{
    std::sort(P, P + Z, pancake_greater);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but If you only want to return the bigest pancake of the pancake list I would implement a memberfunction in the pancakepile class:

```
class pancakepile
{
public:

pancake P[N];
int Z;  
void pan_sort_ascending()
 {

   int mi=max();
     ......
 } 

pancake max()
{
pancake bigestPancake;
foreach(pancake pan, P)
{
if(bigestPancake.Z < pan.Z)
bigestPancake = pan;
}
return bigestPancake;
}
}
```

Edit:
If you want to get the Index of the bigestPancake you can do this instead:

```
class pancakepile
    {
    public:

pancake P[N];
int Z;  
void pan_sort_ascending()
 {

   int mi=max();
     ......
 } 

int max()
{
int bigestPancakeIndex;
for(int i = 0; i < P.size(); i++)
{
if(P[bigestPancakeIndex].Z < P[i].Z)
bigestPancakeIndex= i
}
return bigestPancakeIndex;
}
}
```

Comment: Actually what I want to return is the biggest pancake's index

Comment: Why do you use a non meber function in your member function. That is realy strange.

Comment: I am not sure about the member function that your talk about. But maybe because I am not familiar with the coding style of c++

Comment: Now you get the index

Comment: @SHANGZHOU no idea what Ahrtaler is refering to, its rather common to prefer non-member functions over member functions if possible, see eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921685/4117728

Comment: @user463035818 It is always possible to use a non-member function. That would mean that you would never use a member function. And that would mean that objectiv programming is not common. Especialy in this situation I would perfer the member function.

Comment: @Ahrtaler no it is not always possible to use a non-member. Certain operators can only be implemented as member functions and when the method needs to access private members, then of course making it a member is the way to go, though when you dont need to access private members, then making it a non-member is preferable. Consider that for example when you have `Foo` and a `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const Foo&);` then this overload is considered as part of the public interface of `Foo` even though its not a member

Comment: @user463035818 Ofcourse you are right with your Foo example. In this case It would be perferable. Ofcourse there are some other casese, where it is preferable to use non-member functions. But I think the max function does not belong to this cases.

Comment: to some extend it is a matter of style. You might be interested in reading this article: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197

Comment: Thank you for this article. I will read it this evening. I am realy excited.